# "I did not grew / grow up" - which one is the correct tense?

Tags: verbs, tenses, past-tense, modal-verbs

There are actually quite a few threads on the question of grew or grow up, but none with the verb *did* and the state "being poor" instead of a location, so I allow myself to ask it here. Which sentence is correct:

> I did not grow up poor.

or

> I did not grew up poor.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: The first is correct. The second has two tense-makers, that is, did and grew (= did + grow); hence it is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first sentence is correct. The second sentence is not.

The second one is wrong because "grew" is in the wrong tense.

The "grew" is in the past tense which conflicts with the "did"

The "did" is a past tense auxiliary verb, which can not support another past tense verb such as "grew"

The first sentance has "did" followed by a verb (remember, a verb is fine, but a past tense verb is not)

This is why the first one is correct.

[https://www.learnersdictionary.com/qa/did-main-verb-base-form-or-past-tense-form#:~:text=The%20auxiliary%20verb%20(did)%20is,the%20main%20verb%20is%20not.&text=However%2C%20in%20a%20sentence%20about,in%20the%20past%20tense%20form](https://www.learnersdictionary.com/qa/did-main-verb-base-form-or-past-tense-form#:%7E:text=The%20auxiliary%20verb%20(did)%20is,the%20main%20verb%20is%20not.&text=However%2C%20in%20a%20sentence%20about,in%20the%20past%20tense%20form))

https://www.quora.com/When-do-you-say-grew-up-or-have-grown-up-or-have-been-growing-up-in-English

Comment: Hello, Ian. ELU is aimed at linguists. Even our sister site, ELL, intended for more basic questions, would probably not consider this a suitable question. Answering such on ELU detracts from the site's credibility; it is aimed at linguists – as stated at the Help Center and in the 'Tour'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Ok. Just to clarify though, I should not have answered the question - right? Or was my answer not credible or correct.

Comment: @Ian54: I should not have asked this question here on ELU. Thank you very much for your answer anyway. I will pay more attention to picking the right stack next time and apologise for any inconvenience.

Comment: You may want to look at the debates here on whether there are just two tenses in English (present simple; past simple) (plus a range of clever constructions to get round the fact that there are only two), **or** whether 'future', 'past continuous', 'past perfect' ... are also 'tenses'. But ELL is for basic questions ... and some research shown with questions is helpful there, too. Google ngrams for _I did not grow  up_ and _I did not grew up_ would be a start.

Comment: [I did not grow up,I did not grew up](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+did+not+grow+up%2CI+did+not+grew+up&year_start=1990&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3).